# Why in an isotropic, linear and homogeneous dielectric, the average electric moment can be expanded as a series of electric field $\mathbf{E}$?

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dielectric, dipole, dipole-moment

As I was reading this classic 1939 document by Kirkwood  [The Dielectric Polarization of Polar Liquids](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1750343). It is stated in the text that the average electric moment in an isotropic liquid can be expanded as a power series of the electric field $\mathbf{E}$:

$$
\bar{p} = p_1 E + p_2E^2 + \cdots \tag{1}
$$

And when the electrical saturation is ignored, only the first linear term can be kept, where the coefficient $p_1$ of the first term is expressed as:

$$
\epsilon - 1 = 4 \pi N p_1/v
$$

Where $N$ is Avogadro's number and $v$ is the molar volume.

My question is two. First, I can understand the series expansion of $\bar{p}$ as a function of $E$, but why the expression of the coefficient $p_1$ of the first term is eq(2). The second question is what is the electrical saturation, After ignoring it, why the average electric moment and electric field become linear relationship.

Comment: @Farcher This link answers part of the question, thank you very much. But why the coefficient p_1 of the first term is eq(2) has not been answered yet

Comment: The first term is really the definition of the linear aspect of the dielectric constant.  Higher terms move the dielectric into the saturation region.